# Printing out saved CSV file path from pandas in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv

I am working on a code that need to show an notification where saved csv file's path need to be printed that is obtained from Pandas df.to_csv() method.

my question is "is there any way to get the path file to generated csv file?"

Thank you.
[image]

I am expecting some way to get saved csv file's path so that it can be in place of xxxxxxxx.

Answer (score 0):

You can optionally add a path to `DataFrame.to_csv()` as per the `path_or_buf` argument. Simply define where you are saving the file then print this file path. For example:

```
path = '/User/documents/python/data.csv'
DataFrame.to_csv(path_or_buf=path)
print(path)
```